# Local function definition are illegal

Tags: c++

So I'm messing around with calling functions in C++ since I am still very new to this language and I've been stuck on this error for like 20 minutes and I can't find an answer anywhere. It keeps on giving me the error : `error C2601: 'TimesTwo : local function definitions are illegal` and the same for my `Test` function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int TimesTwo(int num1);
int Test(int a);

int main()
{
    int TimesTwo(int num1)
    {
        int result;
        result = num1 * 2;

        return result;
    }

    int Test(int a)
    {
        int result;
        int num1;
        cin >> num1;
        result = TimesTwo(num1);
        return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have two function definitions inside your `main {}`. Move them outside of `main{}` , and invoke them inside your `main` as needed.

Comment: Why are you _trying_ to define `TimesTwo` and `Test` inside the definition of `main`? If you have a reason, someone can explain how to do what you actually want to do. If you don't… then just don't do it.

Comment: What a disaster of a programming language. It is truly beyond me how software as complex as games are written in C++. No local functions in C++? Oh my goodness.

Answer (score 3):

You have the functions `Test` and `TestTwo` **inside** your `main` function.

Answer (score 2):

While local function definitions as above are illegal C++ supports local functions by means of lambdas. The following is legal in C++11 and later.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto TimesTwo = [](int num1)
    {
        int result;
        result = num1 * 2;

        return result;
    };

    auto Test = [&TimesTwo](int a)
    {
        int result;
        int num1;
        cin >> num1;
        result = TimesTwo(num1);
        return result;
    };

    using fp = int (*)(int);
    fp f1 = TimesTwo; // non-capturing lambda can be converted to function pointer.
    
    return 0;
}
```

A helpful feature of lambdas is that lambdas that do not capture anything can be converted to a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Define your functions outside the `main` routine.

Answer (score 0):

Only to cover the problem mentioned in title: usually this error means you are missing "}" that closes *previous* funciton.